# What is the correct way to concatenate a string?

Tags: javascript, json

```
var d=getEntity( {"Division": 
{
"oddTerms": 
    [           
        {
              "entity": "Sunshine",
              "Sunshine": [
                    {
                         "count": 2,
                        "entity": "Dodge"
                    },
                    {
                        "count": 1,
                        "entity": "Dodge Avenger"
                    },

              ]
        }
  ]

}});
```

I want to traverse through the json string and the the entity names Dodge and Dodge Avenger. Ive used the following method

```
for (var k in h.Division.oddTerms)
{
s=h.Division.oddTerms[k].entity;
h.Division.oddTerms[k].+s+.entity;
}
```

But I do think this its not the correct methd to concatenate as it is not wrking.. anyone knows the correct format?

Comment: What are you expecting the last line in your loop to do?

Comment: I would alert it for instance.. bt I should get the value of entity Dodge and Dodge avenger alerted...

Comment: s will have the value sunshine from the second last line and in the last line, it should append the value sunshine and get the entity names. I am trying this coz if the string contains more than one elements , it will have more values than jst sunshine..

Comment: Okay. So with the specific JSON above, what values do you want to display? For example: "Sunshine: Dodge, Dodge Avenger" or maybe "Sunshine: Dodge","Sunshine: Dodge Avenger"...

Comment: {Sunshine:[ Dodge, Dodge Avenger ]}  This is the way I want my output to be displayed...

Comment: I've updated the code in my answer to give the output in the form you requested. I've added quotes to the output because it looks like you're producing a JSON string. I'm also using an output 'template'. The `%entityName` and `%terms` are just there to make search/replace easier to see -- it doesn't have any "magic" meaning in JS.

Comment: but this one is for fixed numbers..What if the entities have more than two level. It should use recursion..right?

Comment: In that case, recursion is probably best. You might want to build this out using a "class" structure (`arrEntities.push(new Entity(entityName, terms))`. The problem with trying to pass through a complex data structure is that you'll be doing lots nested loops. I personally find it easier to think in terms of simple models.

Comment: Is it possible for you to help me with the recursion?? I m new to that one..

Answer (score 1):

`oddTerms` is an Array, not an Object. For arrays in JavaScript you need to use a for loop with a counter instead of iterating through the elements:

```
var concatedString = '';
for (var k=0; k<h.Division.oddTerms.length;k++)
{
    // Get the name of the entity we want to collect the entity terms of
    var entityName =h.Division.oddTerms[k].entity;
    // iterate through all the instances of each entity
    for(var j=0; j<h.Division.oddTerms[k][entityName].length;j++){
      concatedString += h.Division.oddTerms[k][entityName][j].entity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats not the issue,for (var k in h.Division.oddTerms) wil wrk like the foreach loop in php, the issue is with the way I appending that variable s with the value Sunshine in to the 'h.Division.oddTerms[k].+s+.entity;'

Answer (score 0):

```
var entityName = "",
    arrTerms = [],
    outputTemplate = '{"%entityName":[%terms]}',
    h = {
        "Division":
        {
            "oddTerms":
            [
                {
                    "entity": "Sunshine",
                    "Sunshine": [
                    {
                        "count": 2,
                        "entity": "Dodge"
                    },
                    {
                        "count": 1,
                        "entity": "Dodge Avenger"
                    },

                    ]
                }
            ]

        }
    };

for (var i = 0; i <  h.Division.oddTerms.length; i++)
{
    entityName=h.Division.oddTerms[i].entity; // "Sunshine"
    terms = h.Division.oddTerms[i][entityName];

    for (var j = 0; j < terms.length; j++) {
        arrTerms.push('"' + terms[j].entity + '"');
    }
}

// This will give you '{"Sunshine":["Dodge","Dodge Avenger"]}':
console.log(outputTemplate.replace('%entityName', entityName).replace('%terms', arrTerms.join(",")));
```

---

Edit:

Just some more on this.

JSON can be a bit confusing to work with if you're not used to working with JS and object and array "literals". In JS you can define objects and arrays in a number of ways, but the easiest (and the most preferred, by many developers) is with these literals.

Here's an example of an object:

```
var myObj = {
    "some prop":"some value",
    "anotherProp":"another value"
}
```

You can look up the members of `myObj` in several ways:

`myObj.anotherProp` // "another value"

`myObj["some prop"]` // you have to use this form if the property name has a space in it

For looping through the contents of an array, use the second form. For example, this won't work:

```
for (var strPropName in myObj) {
   console.log(myObj.strPropName); // This won't work!
}
```

Instead, you should loop through the properties like this:

```
for (var strPropName in myObj) {
    if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(strPropName)) {
       console.log(myObj[strPropName]);
    }
}
```

The `if` block is optional, but you'll avoid potential problems if you always include this in your code. It's also required by some validators.

Now, here's an example of an array:

```
var myArray = ["some value", "anotherValue"];
```

You access these with a numeric index:

```
myArray[0] // "some value"
myArray[1] // "anotherValue"
myArray[2] // undefined
```

And you can loop through them:

```
for (var index = 0; index < myArray.length; index++) {
    console.log(myArray[index]);
}
```

You can nest objects inside arrays:

```
myArray = [{},{},{}];
```

And you can nest arrays inside objects:

```
myObject = {"arr1":[], "arr2":[], "arr3":[]}
```

Comment: I'll add some more here to help you along.